# WSO2 BAM 2.5.0 output adapters are missing

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam

I would like to use email output event adapter in WSO2 BAM 2.5.0. So according to documentation I should go to Configure --> Output Event Adapters --> Add Output Event Adapter, but there is no email adapter in select list.

Why?

Where are output adaptors?

According to documentation there should be email, mysql, websocket etc. adapters.

Should I enable something in BAM configs files?

Or it just a bug, if yes, is there any patch?

Here is link to documentation: [Output Event Adapters](https://docs.wso2.com/display/BAM250/Output+Event+Adapters)

Answer (score 1):

The SOAP output event adaptor does not get loaded properly and this is a bug in this version. So you would need to remove the "org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adaptor.soap_1.0.2.jar" file from "repository/components/plugins" directory and restart the server. You should get the email output event adapter to work after doing this.